# temporary disable pci device (AMD?)

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, pci

I'm trying to temporary disable a PCI device, I've searched google and most of them are quite old, trying those methods to no anvil =(

here's what I've tried: putting device ID to the unbind and wait for it to shutdown

`sudo sh -c "echo '0000:05:00.0' > ./unbind`

which works and then my system hanged =(

---

so what's the correct / proper way to shutdown a PCI device (graphics card, AMD to be specific) and turn it back on? thank you so much! =)

Comment: If it is a build in device it should be possible to disable it in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the device power off.

```
echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$N/power
```

where `$N` is the slot number.